# Possibly not handling vector arrays properly (BFS to find shortest distance to all nodes)

Tags: c++, graph-theory, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

This problem is more about programming than competitive programming. I'm relatively a newbie when it comes to writing programs involving Graph Theory. I've explained the question below. I've coded the solution with the apt logic required, but for some reason, my output is not matching the testcases. Please help me out with my code, given below. (NOTE: I've included the testcases, expected output and the output I'm getting at the end of the code)

I'll describe the problem statement shortly:

Given a graph, with each edge having a weight of 6 units (need not be connected), use Breadth First Search to find the shortest distance from a source node to all other nodes.

Link to the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bfsshortreach/problem

Input Format:

> The first line contains an integer , the number of queries. Each of the following  sets of lines has the following format:
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers n and m, the number of nodes and edges in the graph.
>
> Each line  of the m subsequent lines contains two space-separated integers, u and v, describing an edge connecting node u to node v.
>
> The last line contains a single integer, s, denoting the index of the starting node for the BFS procedure.

My Code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue> using namespace std;

void addedge(int u,int v, vector <int> edges[]) {
    edges[u].push_back(v);
    edges[v].push_back(u); 
}
    
void bfs(int n,int m,vector <int> edges[],int s) {
    queue <int> q;
    vector <int> d(n+1);
    for(int o=0;o<n;o++) d[o]=-1;
    q.push(s); d[s]=0;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        int temp=q.front(); q.pop();
        for(auto x : edges[temp])
        {
            if(d[x] == -1) { d[x]=d[temp] + 6; q.push(x);}
        }
    }
    for(auto l=0;l<d.size();l++) cout<<d[l]<<" ";


}
    int main() {
        int q,n,i,m,s,t,u;
        cin>>q;
        for(i=0;i<q;i++)
        {
        cin>>n>>m;
        vector <int> edges[n];
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        { 
        cin>>t>>u; 
        addedge(t,u,edges);
        int s;
        cin>>s;
        bfs(n,m,edges,s); 
        cout<<"\n";
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}

Input:

2
4 2
1 2
1 3
1
3 1
2 3
2

Expected Output:

6 6 -1
-1 6

Actual Output:

-1 0 6 -1 0 
-1 6 12 0 0
```

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Something which is usually not possible for online judge or competition sites as the input is not normally known. So be happy that it *is* possible to debug in your case.

Comment: Actually I've included expected output and actual output at the ending of the code itself. So please help me out, it's been a long time and I haven't been able to sort it out.

Comment: Formatting the code properly will improve its readability. Pay attention to whitespace around operators and proper indentation. The main function looks like it's part of the addedge function

Comment: I've edited the code accordingly. Since I'm a newbie here, this happened, but I'll make sure to make readability is ensured from now onwards :)

Comment: You are redeclaring `s` inside your main function.  Once at the beginning and again within your nested for loop.

Comment: Yes that's right, but changing that didn't change the output, it still doesn't pass the testcases. Strangely, the numbers it is printing seem unusual.

Comment: after some work I got this to compile and run as you seem to expect.  You really need to go back to a point before debugging and go over your design thoroughly.  Take the design statements and use them to write and comment your code.  This work looks like you tried to write a program (small one but still...) with no detailed design work.

Comment: Look up Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: See Dijkstra's algorithm is not at all required here. I can find shortest distance using BFS if the graph is unweighted or all weights are equal in O(V+E) time, instead of using Dijkstra which takes O(ElogV) time.